# Very weird performance drop with a home-made JavaScript toggle class function

Tags: javascript, performance

I have made my own JavaScript class manipulation functions for a small project I'm working on, and they all work great, except for one. The toggle class function.

http://jsperf.com/my-class-functions-and-how-they-perform

As of today, the code is this:

```
tglClass = function(el, className) {
  return !!remClass(el, className) || !!addClass(el, className);
};
```

And I thought the performance drop was a result of addClass and remClass both calling hasClass before they do anything:

```
hasClass = function(el, className) {
  return el.classList.contains(className);
};

addClass = function(el, className) {
  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    return el.className += ' ' + className;
  } return false;
};

remClass = function(el, className) {
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    return el.className = (' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
  } return false;
};
```

But the weird part is that when I rewrite the function to only do hasClass once, performance drops even lower than when doing what I described above.

```
tglNcClass = function(el, className) {
  if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    return el.className = (' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
  } else {
    return el.className += ' ' + className;
  }
};
```

Do you have any ideas what I'm overlooking here? Why are the other functions **that** much faster?

**Updated**

Comment: You can make some optimizations by using `.classList`.

Comment: Also, `hasClass()` should be `return (' ' + el.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') !== -1;`

Comment: In `remClass()` the line `return el.className = el.className.replace(className, '');` will sometimes return a truthy value and sometimes return a falsey value - if you remove the only class it will return an empty string (falsey), otherwise it will return a non-empty string (truthy). Also, if an element has the class `'testing'` and you try to remove `'test'` it will leave `'ing'`. **Make the code reliable before worrying about performance.** No point optimising an error...

Comment: @Jack, thanks, I tried using classList.contains but that was not better performing than using className. I like that hasClass() edit, though, that looks much better!

Comment: @nnnnnn, you're right! I changed to indexOf minutes before posting, I should have tested it - see, I used classList.contains on the hasClass function before switching to indexOf. I think using what Jack suggested fixes this issue.

Comment: Fixing `hasClass()` doesn't solve the remove problem if you keep using `replace()` like that, because what if the starting `className` value is something like `'testing tester test'` and you try to replace `'test'` with an empty string? It also doesn't help with the return value from `remClass()`....

Comment: @nnnnnn True, sorry about that. return el.className = (' ' + el.className + ' ').replace(' test ', ' ') seems to fix the issue - correct me if I'm wrong again.

Comment: Oh, try to test only similar test cases at the same time ;-)

Comment: Also, when removing a class that does not exist, it will return false because of `hasClass()`, but when removing a class that exists and returns an empty string, `!!remClass(el, 'noClassesLeftAfterThis')` is still true.